# FutureWarning: `TemplateForHostMiddleware` is deprecated. Please upgrade to the template loader

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am building a [mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) website.

I installed mezzanine by typing `pip install mezzanine` this installed django 1.9 (IIRC) along with mezzanine.

I then installed [cartridge](http://cartridge.jupo.org/), which upgraded django to version 1.10.8.

Now when I run `runserver` at the command line, I get the following warning at the command line:

> /path/to/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:58:
>   FutureWarning: TemplateForHostMiddleware` is deprecated. Please
>   upgrade to the template loader.

How do I resolve this warning - as the warning is not very clear (i.e. upgrade ***which*** template loader and also, what does it mean to upgrade the template loader?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this portion](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/1f920b64930c314da8058dcf5690caa7b157e570/docs/multi-tenancy.rst#upgrading-from-templateforhostmiddleware) of the documentation which explains what is going on:

> Mezzanine implements host-specific templates using a template loader since version 4.3. Prior to that, the `TemplateForHostMiddleware` was used. If you are upgrading from a version lower than 4.3 and getting warnings in the terminal about `TemplateForHostMiddleware`, edit your settings.py to switch to the new loader-based approach:
>
> - Remove `TemplateForHostMiddleware` from your `MIDDLEWARE` or `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.
> - Remove `"APP_DIRS": True` from your `TEMPLATES` setting.
> - Add `mezzanine.template.loaders.host_themes.Loader` to the list of template loaders.
>
> Your TEMPLATES setting should look like this (notice the "loaders" key):
>
> ```
> TEMPLATES = [
>   {
>       "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
>       "DIRS": [...],
>       "OPTIONS": {
>           "context_processors": [...],
>           "builtins": [...],
>           "loaders": [
>               "mezzanine.template.loaders.host_themes.Loader",
>               "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
>               "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
>           ]
>       },
>   },
> ]
> ```

Looks like this change to the documentation hasn't made it to http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/multi-tenancy.html .